# Concatenate MySQL columns - Error 1054

Tags: mysql

I am trying to merge two fields into one, in one of my MySQL tables (columns titled "firstname" and "lastname," respectively, for all entries in the table). I have scoured several posts on the matter here and have yet to find a solution that works.

I keep receiving...

```
Error #1054  - Unknown column 'firstname' in 'field list'
```

...when I try to execute the following:

```
SELECT concat(firstname, ' ', lastname)
```

I have double-checked the spelling of both fields and they are correct. They are both VARCHAR.

I am a relative newbie to MySQL, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the *complete* `SELECT` statement, as well as the output from `SHOW CREATE whatever_you_named_your_table`.

Comment: That was the complete SELECT statement... I gather that's where I've gone wrong...?

Comment: Is that your full query `select concat(firstname, ' ', lastname)`? You might want to write something like `select concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) as fullname from tablename`

Comment: Yes. To select the contents of a column, you also have to specify the table where the column exists.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see from the error message is that either the columns are not there( which seems not true because of your comment) or you are not accessing them properly, try to use table name before the fields :

```
SELECT concat(tbl.firstname, ' ', tbl.lastname) from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this:

```
select concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) as fullname
from yourTableName
```

Comment: Ok, this worked, but when I go back to browse the table I still see the original two columns, and not the new one.

Comment: The query extracts data and does not make any change to the database. That is the beauty about databases. You can store relevant information such as firstname and lastname in the database. When you want to extract data, you can transform that data on the fly just like in the query above. There is no need to store relevant (firstname and last name) and derived (full name) data in the database.

Comment: I see. What I would like to do is eliminate the separate firstname/lastname fields and have only one fullname field. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: You can do that but I'd recommend to not do that. Once you combine the fields, separating them will be a royal pain. So just don't do that. If you are very inclined to combining them, you can do `alter table tablename add column fullname varchar(100);`. Then update this field `update tablename set fullname = concat(firstname, ' ', lastname);`. Then remove the two columns `alter table tablename drop column firstname; alter table tablename drop column lastname;`